# (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError:(function) is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, api, onchange

I am using React to build a small API based web app and have run into problem. I'm following a tutorial and this code works for him - but not me. I am at a complete loss on what to do!
My html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Geodoggies </h1>

    <div id = "breed">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS

```
//fetches the breed list
async function start() {
  const response = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
  const data = await response.json()
  createBreedList(data.message)
}
start()

//creates the select element for dog breeds
function createBreedList(breedList) {
  document.getElementById('breed').innerHTML = `
    <select onchange="loadByBreed(this.value)">
      
    <option>Choose a dog breed</option>
      ${Object.keys(breedList)
        .map(function (breed) {
          return `<option>${breed}</option>`
        })
        .join('')}
     </select>
  `
}

function loadByBreed(breed) {
  alert(breed)
  // if (breed !== 'Choose a dog breed') {
  //   const response = await fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images`)
  //   const data = await response.json()
  //   console.log(data)
  // }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: why is this question tagged with reactjs? I don't see any relevance of React to your code, it appears to just use vanilla JS. (And there's absolutely nothing wrong with that, it just means your tag is likely to draw in people who expect to be answering React questions, which unless I have missed something, this is not.)

Comment: Like @RobinZigmond said, the tutorial you're following is essentially not showing you any react code currently. I would suggest changing the questions tags. Also I tested your code: https://codepen.io/arlcode/pen/ZEezRxJ I see no errors.